# Java program not returning any values

Tags: java

I am currently working on a class assignment and cannot figure out why I am getting the output that I am getting. The programming question is:

> You operate several hotdog stands. Define a class named `HotDogStand`
>   that has an instance variable for the hot dog stand's ID number and an
>   instance variable for how many hot dogs the stand has sold that day.
>   Create a constructor that allows a user of the class to initialize
>   both variables. Also create a method named `justSold` that increments by
>   one the number of hot dogs the stand has sold. The idea is that this
>   method will be invoked each time the stand sells a hot dog so the
>   total can be tracked. Add another method that returns the number of
>   hot dogs sold.
>
> Add a static variable that tracks the total number of hot dogs sold by
>   all the stands and a static method that returns the value in this
>   variable.

So my code is:

```
public class HotDogStand {
    // instance variable declaration
    private int IDNumber;
    private int hotDogsSold = 0;
    private static int totalSold = 0;

    public HotDogStand(int ID, int sold) {
        IDNumber = ID;
        hotDogsSold = sold;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return IDNumber;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        IDNumber = ID;
    }

    public void justSold() {
        if (hotDogsSold > 0) {
            hotDogsSold++;
        }
    }

    public int sold() {
        return hotDogsSold;
    }

    public static int getTotal() {
        return totalSold;
    }
}
```

And my testing class is:

```
public class HotDogTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HotDogStand stand1 = new HotDogStand(1, 11);
        HotDogStand stand2 = new HotDogStand(2, 17);
        HotDogStand stand3 = new HotDogStand(3, 6);

        stand1.getID();
        stand2.getID();
        stand3.getID();
        stand1.setID(1);
        stand2.setID(2);
        stand3.setID(3);
        stand1.justSold();
        stand2.justSold();
        stand3.justSold();
        stand1.justSold();
        stand1.justSold();
        stand1.justSold();
        stand3.justSold();

        stand1.getTotal();
        stand2.getTotal();
        stand3.getTotal();

        int grandTotal = stand1.getTotal() + stand2.getTotal() + stand3.getTotal();

        System.out.println("Stand " + stand1.getID() + " sold a total of " + stand1.getTotal() + " hotdogs.");
        System.out.println("Stand " + stand2.getID() + " sold a total of " + stand2.getTotal() + " hotdogs.");
        System.out.println("Stand " + stand3.getID() + " sold a total of " + stand3.getTotal() + " hotdogs.");

        System.out.println("The total amount of hotdogs sold by all the stands was " + grandTotal);
    }
}
```

My output is:

> Stand 1 sold a total of 0 hotdogs.
>   Stand 2 sold a total of 0 hotdogs.
>   Stand 3 sold a total of 0 hotdogs.
>   The total amount of hotdogs sold by all the stands was 0

Comment: You are incrementing `hotDogsSold` but printing `getTotal()` which returns `totalSold`.

Comment: What do you try to achieve with that: `if (hotDogsSold > 0) { hotDogsSold++; }`?

Comment: A bit unclear what you want with the procedures. Use more clear name with get or set/update/increase in the function names or descriptions.

Comment: you are missing `this` keyword at a lotta places.. When you make an object of a type (in this case of `HotDogStand ` type) like, `HotDogStand stand1 = new HotDogStand(1, 11);` , you are passing these int values to that particular instance of `HotDogStand()` i.e., stand1 so update the constructor with `public HotDogStand(int ID, int sold) {
       this. IDNumber = ID;
       this.hotDogsSold = sold;
    }`. Hint: read about getters and setters. U need to use them, refine your logic for `jusSold()` method, you should be good then. :) I could provide you with new code base but wont help you learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point at which you change the `totalSold` variable. `justsold` increments the instance variable `hotDogsSold` but `getTotal` return `totalSold`.

You need a method `getSold` which returns the instance variable `hotDogsSold`.

The other problem is that `totalSold` is a static variable (it's a class variable; it's not tied to any individual instance of the class like hot dog seller 1 or 2 but rather to the entire model of hot dog sellers). As a result, your grand total would, if `totalSold` were incremented correctly, give 3 times the number of sold hot dogs for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

you are never updating totalSold field. Increment that as well inside justSold() method's if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void justSold() {
    if (hotDogsSold > 0) {
        totalSold = hotDogsSold++;
    }
```